# alter .txt file and save it with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am doing classic find&replace in some .txt file with powershell.
How can I "save" file at the end? I tried with | Set-Content but nothing happens.
Maybe I need to Add-Content first?

```
#Find what?
$optionBuilderStringToFind = "optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer"
$findUsingKeywordString = "using Microsoft."

#Replace with
$namespaceAdd = "using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;"
$optionBuilderConfigurable ="optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString(`"Database`") 
 );"

gc -Path .\APSContext.cs | % { 
if ($_ -match "using System;") {
    $_ = $_ + "`n" + $namespaceAdd
    #write-host $_
}
if ($_ -match "optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer") {
    $_ = $optionBuilderConfigurable
    #write-host $_
}
} | Set-Content -Path .\test.cs
```

Update: Here is testFile where I am looking to alter it. The content of the file is not important. I want to add another reference like "using Something.Something" and in the middle of the file to replace `"optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("dfjidfjljfiejf88");"` with `"optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("_configtest");"`:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace SRC.APS.Model.APSDB
{
public partial class APSContext : DbContext
{
    public APSContext()
    {
    }

    public APSContext(DbContextOptions<APSContext> options)
        : base(options)
       protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("dfjidfjljfiejf88");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.0-rtm-35687");

    }
```

Maybe I need to use Out-String instead?

Comment: `set-content` should work but I would use `Out-File`

Comment: out-file gives me an empty file..but I want to replaceold file with a new one..

Comment: Have you tried writing the modified file to a temp filename? If that works, then delete he original and rename the temp filename.

Comment: for some strange reason, if I remove Foreach-Object clause, then I get test.cs file filled with text. If I just put in pipeline | % {write-host $_} then produces blank test.cs

Comment: _usually_ you want to avoid fiddling with the _current item_ [`$_`] variable. use it as input, but don't write to it. so, instead of this `$_ = $_ + "`n" + $namespaceAdd`, i would use '$_ + "``n" + $namespaceAdd` and let that go to the pipeline. for any later processing, and eventually get sent to the output file.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I agree with you, but I cannot understand why I am getting blank out file. As I said, if I remove foreach object pipeline, and leave just gc | out-file, it works perfetly, but I need to alter some lines in my txt (.cs) file

Comment: without seeing the input data, i can't make any realistic guess about the why of it. [*frown*] i'm not a good all-in-the-mind scripter - i need concrete stuff to work out the why of things ... and even then will miss the why sometimes. ///// i don't see any glaring error in your logic, so i don't know where the glitch may be.

Comment: actually, i suspect that the `$_` fiddling IS the answer. [*grin*] you are not supposed to touch that. when you skip the pipeline, the `$_` doesn't exist ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I updated my question with .cs example

Comment: You are getting a blank output file because your `ForEach-Object` body does not output any lines. It does set `$_` to a different value, but it does not put anything on the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any script block in Powershell can produce values. This is done by *not* storing a value in a variable:

- `{ $foo = 3 }` produces nothing
- `{ 3 }` produces the integer `3`.

In the same way

- `ForEach-Object { $_ = "something" }` produces nothing
- `ForEach-Object { $_ = "something"; $_ }` produces the string `"something"`

Your loop body does not output anything, it's like the upper example above. Therefore, `Set-Content` has nothing to do. Modify the block to actually return the changed value of `$_`:

```
$replacements = @(
    @{regex='using (System|Potentially|Others);'; replacement='using Microsoft.$1;' }
    @{regex='optionsBuilder\.UseSqlServer\("[^"]*"\)'; replacement='optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Database")' }
    # more search/replace pairs
)

Get-Content .\APSContext.cs -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($item in $replacements) {
        $_ = $_ -replace $item.regex, $item.replacement
    }
    $_   # <--- this is what produces the line
} | Set-Content -Path .\test.cs -Encoding UTF8
```

That being said, never load or save text files without specifying their encoding. For C# source code files, I think UTF-8 is the default.

And **that** being said, modifying source code with regular expressions is not a good thing to do. If this is a one-off, fine. If you plan to do this on a regular basis, you are doing something wrong. Work with configuration files or environment variables instead of keeping in your codebase literal values that are subject to regular change.

Comment: thanks @Tomalak, now is clear to me why I didn't get any value.

Answer (score 0):

as i mentioned - and as Tomalak pointed out - your mucking with the current pipeline object is the source of the glitch. [*grin*] this code fixes a logic error in your IF cascade [which may be better done with a `switch` block], removes the unwise `$_` fiddling, and then ensures there is always some output.

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace SRC.APS.Model.APSDB
{
public partial class APSContext : DbContext
{
    public APSContext()
    {
    }

    public APSContext(DbContextOptions<APSContext> options)
        : base(options)
       protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("dfjidfjljfiejf88");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.0-rtm-35687");

    }
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

#Find what?
$optionBuilderStringToFind = "optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer"
$findUsingKeywordString = "using Microsoft."

#Replace with
$namespaceAdd = 'using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;'
$optionBuilderConfigurable ='optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Database"));'

$InStuff | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_ -match "using System;")
        {
        $_ + "`n" + $namespaceAdd
        #write-host $_
        }
        elseif ($_ -match "optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer")
        {
        $optionBuilderConfigurable
        #write-host $_
        }
        else
        {
        $_
        }
    }
```

output ...

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace SRC.APS.Model.APSDB
{
public partial class APSContext : DbContext
{
    public APSContext()
    {
    }

    public APSContext(DbContextOptions<APSContext> options)
        : base(options)
       protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {

optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Database"));
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.0-rtm-35687");

    }
```